# WP7 Silverlight grid prerender or similar?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have to do some manipulation of a silverlight grid in code behind. I am currently doing this in the Grid_loaded event. This isn't ideal as the grid loads then flashes with the changes made by the code. This is clearly because the manipulation is done after the grid has loaded. The manpulation I need to do cannot be done with databinding.

Is there somewhere else that I can put this code? In asp .net I would do it in a prerender.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can hide the grid while it is not ready?

Comment: How about you bother to explain what you actually needs to do. And I don't believe you, when you say it can't be done with databindings. Sounds more like lack of experience with Silverlight.

Comment: Hiding the grid would be an option I guess. WhatI'm trying to do is set the background of the rows in the grid to use a string url that points to the image to use. If that an be done using databinding I would love some pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Also, how about animating the Opacity of the Image? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got databinding working so the problem is solved. I am binding on to a property like this...

```
public object ListingBG
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListingBGString))
                {
                    // bind Image
                    return new ImageBrush
                    {
                        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ListingBGString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
                    };
                }
                // bind color hex (RGB hex or RGB+Alpha hex)
                return "#FFFFFFFF";
            }
        }
```